# Access Php globally from terminal ubuntu 16.04 lts

Tags: php, xampp

[image]

I have installed xampp on my machine  .. all running good but when i type `php` in terminal that suggest me to install from apt-get

So want to get rid off this and i am new to Ubuntu .. help will be appreciated thanks

Answer (score 3):

This is simple just create a symlink. I just did this with a fresh install of **Ubuntu 18.0.4 Bionic Beaver** and **XAMPP x64-7.4.4-0-installer**. Just execute the following command in the terminal

```
sudo ln -s /opt/lampp/bin/php /usr/bin/php
```

Answer (score 0):

Where you installed XAMPP? You remember the path? You need looking for PHP binary somewhere there.

If you don't remeber the path, maybe this will be help: `sudo find / -name 'php'`. When you will be have path, you need add this into `PATH` variable - [How to add a directory to the PATH?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-my-path)

Comment: php is using in that locations
 /opt/phpstorm/plugins/php
/opt/lampp/lib/php
/opt/lampp/include/php
/opt/lampp/php
/opt/lampp/bin/php
So what path put into environment variables for access php globally to install composer or etc

Comment: I think it will be `/opt/lampp/bin/php`, so you need add directory `/opt/lampp/bin/` to your `PATH` variable

Comment: Same result after setting path..

Comment: I put screenshot link on my post ..

Comment: Show me `echo $PATH`

Comment: # set PATH so it includes user's private bin directories
PATH="$HOME/bin:$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
PATH="$PATH:/opt/lampp/bin/php"

Comment: /home/rizwan/bin:/home/rizwan/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/opt/lampp/bin/php:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin:/opt/lampp/bin/php

Comment: You need add directory path to `PATH` variable, not path to PHP binary! So add `/opt/lampp/bin/` instant of `/opt/lampp/bin/php`

Comment: Yaah that is the thing i was going wrong .. Thanks for help problem is solved .. :)

Comment: @RizwanArshad Can you mark an answer as correct? (The green check)